# IIF of SWITCH output is limited at length 255

Tags: sql, ms-access, enterprise-architect, jet

For a custom SQL query in Enterprise Architect we are using IIF or SWITCH, but both seem to have a limitation on their output.

Is there any way to bypass this limitation?

As a simple example below a query with the limitation

```
select 
switch(true, note) as NoteAfterSwitch,
Cstr(switch(true, note)) as NoteAfterCstrSwitch,
switch(true, cstr(note)) as CstrNoteAfterSwitch,
Cvar(switch(true, note)) as NoteAfterCVarSwitch,
switch(true, cvar(note)) as CvarNoteAfterSwitch,
Note
from t_object as t
where t.object_id = 115
```

The column NoteAfterSwitch is limited at 255 chars.
While the original Note has more then 255 chars.
We want to use the original size.

In column NoteAfterCstrSwitch and CstrNoteAfterSwitch we tried using CStr, but also without success.

In column NoteAfterCvarSwitch and CvarNoteAfterSwitch we tried using Cvar, but also without success.

**Edit**
We also tried to use JET 4.0, but unfortunately without success. It resulted in a scrambled output:

[image]

Comment: _"We tried using CStr and CVar, but without success."_ What exactly did you try?

Comment: We tried within and outside the switch
    Cstr(switch(true, note)) as 1
    switch(true, cstr(note)) as 2

Comment: Do you mean you tried wrapping both arguments in those functions? See, it would be so much easier just to post the exact code that you tried.

Comment: I will edit the original post

Comment: [link](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html) is about these limitations. But I'm still not sure how to handle this problem

Comment: Just to confirm: If you simply retrieve the [note] column without an IIF or SWITCH function then the entire field (>255 characters) is returned?

Comment: I just tried a SQLQuery with a Notes result that returned more than 255 chars. So it's probably connected to the functions you use, not EA itself.

Comment: @GordThompson yes, without any function the full length is returned

Comment: @ThomasKilian I agree, the limitations must be in Access / Jet db engine that EA is using.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but EA ships with Jet3 and you can optionally switch to Jet4.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thanks, I tried it through the [Workspace > Preferences](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/user_interface/generalsettings.html), but unfortunately I didn't work out. 
It did something already but not what we expected. The output is some longer but everything above 255 is scrambled in strange characters. I will update the original question with this info.

Comment: For reference: this doesn't happen in a query that is run directly in Access 2010. Neither `IIf` nor `Switch` truncate memo columns. (But things like GROUP BY will, as described in the Allen Browne link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our intern (Kevin) found the solution on a [Austrian blog](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2014/08/26/enterprise-architect-sql-issue-on-selecting-note-fields/).
We have do an implicit cast before the `IIF` or `Switch` does it.
And that can be done with an empty `union`:

```
SELECT  Note as notes
FROM    t_object AS o
where   1 = 0
union all
select  switch(true, o.note)
FROM    t_object AS o
WHERE   o.Object_ID = 115
```

This trick should also work with other implicit unwanted cast actions.

Comment: Note: We use this function for template fragments, but it should also work on other Custom SQL queries